# MS SQL PIVOT MONTH, QUARTER AND YEAR- The QUARTER Showing Wrong Data for If Similar Month Values Present

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot-table, unpivot

I am having the following data structure in the table.

```
UNITDATE    UNIT
2020-01-01  550.00
2020-01-01  777.00
2020-02-01  887.00
2020-02-01  111.00
2020-03-01  501.00
2020-03-01  500.00
2020-04-01  516.00
2020-05-01  516.00
2020-06-01  723.00
```

But the following pivot query return wrong results for quarter SUM(Q2) because 2020-04-01 and 2020-05-01 has same value.

```
SELECT SUM([1]) AS Jan, SUM([2]) AS Feb, SUM([3]) AS Mar,SUM(Q1) AS Q1,  
                SUM([4]) AS Apr, SUM([5]) AS May, SUM([6]) AS Jun, SUM(Q2) AS Q2, 
                SUM([7]) AS Jul, SUM([8]) AS Aug, SUM([9]) AS Sep, SUM(Q3) AS Q3,
                SUM([10]) AS Oct, SUM([11]) AS Nov, SUM([12]) AS Dec, SUM(Q4) AS Q4, SUM([2020]) AS YEARLY 
        FROM (SELECT  
        DATEPART(MONTH, UNITDATE) as month,
        CAST('Q' + CAST(DATEPART(QUARTER, UNITDATE) AS VARCHAR(1)) AS VARCHAR(2)) AS quarter,
        DATEPART(YEAR, UNITDATE) as year,
        SUM(UNIT) AS M,
        SUM(UNIT) AS Q,
        SUM(UNIT) AS Y FROM MyTable WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, UNITDATE) = 2020 GROUP BY UNITDATE) as yearData 
        PIVOT (SUM(M) FOR month IN ( [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])) AS PM     
        PIVOT (SUM(Q) FOR quarter IN ([Q1],[Q2],[Q3],[Q4])) AS PQ
        PIVOT (SUM(Y) FOR year IN ([2020])) AS PY;

Jan Feb Mar Q1  Apr May Jun Q2  Jul Aug Sep Q3  Oct Nov Dec Q4  YEARLY
1327.00 998.00  1001.00 3326.00 516.00  516.00  723.00  1239.00 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    4565.00
```

Could some one faced the similar issue please advice.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the `PIVOT` operator, it's restrictive and clunky. A conditional aggregate would be *far* easier:

```sql
WITH YourData AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM(VALUES(CONVERT(date,'2020-01-01'),550.00),
               (CONVERT(date,'2020-01-01'),777.00),
               (CONVERT(date,'2020-02-01'),887.00),
               (CONVERT(date,'2020-02-01'),111.00),
               (CONVERT(date,'2020-03-01'),501.00),
               (CONVERT(date,'2020-03-01'),500.00),
               (CONVERT(date,'2020-04-01'),516.00),
               (CONVERT(date,'2020-05-01'),516.00),
               (CONVERT(date,'2020-06-01'),723.00))V(UNITDATE,UNIT))
SELECT SUM(CASE DATEPART(MONTH,UNITDATE) WHEN 1 THEN UNIT END) AS Jan,
       SUM(CASE DATEPART(MONTH,UNITDATE) WHEN 2 THEN UNIT END) AS Feb,
       SUM(CASE DATEPART(MONTH,UNITDATE) WHEN 3 THEN UNIT END) AS Mar,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH,UNITDATE) BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN UNIT END) AS Q1,
       SUM(CASE DATEPART(MONTH,UNITDATE) WHEN 4 THEN UNIT END) AS Apr,
       -- You get the idea
       SUM(UNIT) AS Yearly
FROM YourData
WHERE UNITDATE >= '20200101'
  AND UNITDATE < '20210101';
```

Comment: Thank You, But in performance wise the pivot is better for a large data set right? I have shared a subset of the data which I have in the above post.

Comment: Why do you think a `PIVOT` would be "faster"?

Comment: Not sure , I haven't compared these, But assuming as its CTE pivot will do better. Is that correct.

Comment: A CTE just an expression. A poorly written expression hinders performance, but that isn't the problem here. The query, provided you have an index on `UNITDATE` that `INCLUDE`s `UNIT` would likely be very quick. If you say that `PIVOT` is faster, you need to evidence that with query plans.

Comment: Thank you, also I am new to SQL queries - I didn't get your answer "The query, provided you have an index on UNITDATE that INCLUDEs UNIT would likely be very quick" is there any way to achieve this with my current data set

Comment: It *does* achieve it with the current data set @MobDev . YOu can even copy and paste that into your IDE (with the CTE for sample data) and run it and you'll get the results you are after... [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=85e472c92e711744392157afb155ce21) If you're saying it's not giving the results you expect, then that would suggset the sample data you've supplied isn't representative of your real data.

Comment: Yes tried the query you have shared and its working correctly, Thank You

Comment: @MobDev If you examine the query plan, you will see that `PIVOT` compiles down to the same `MAX(CASE` expressions, so it's exactly the same